# Putting a multi-module Maven project into Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I need to set up a multi-module Maven project to build in Jenkins (version 1.534).   Each module is in its own Git repository, completely separate from each other:

```
/home/git/ProjectDomain.git
/home/git/ProjectWAR.git
```

Locally I've built my own parent POM.XML and have each project in a subfolder:

```
<modules>
    <module>ProjectSupport</module>
    <module>ProjectWAR</module>
</modules>
```

This works locally but I can't get it working on Jenkins, and I can't seem to find any online documentation to show how to do this.   Anyone have a good reference for this?

EDIT:  The current Parent pom I am trying to use is in the /ProjectWAR folder, and looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Project</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>../ProjectDomain</module>
        <module>../ProjectWAR</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Once again it works locally, but not on Jenkins.   The error I am currently getting is this:

```
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project - Integration/workspace/../ProjectDomain/pom.xml: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project - Integration/workspace/../ProjectDomain/pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
```

So somehow, I need to tell it where the ProjectDomain repo is, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: have you considered whether it should be a multi-module build in the first place?  If they live in separate source control locations, perhaps the better maven relationship is simply as a dependency.

Comment: @chad - I'm currently exploring that.   Our source control and build process is a real rat's nest and the people who set it up are either no longer here, or are tired of answering questions about it.  So, many things are a mystery to me.  :)

Comment: The idea of a multi-module build is having the same version and to release to the same time. This implies that the tree of the different modules should be in the same git repository.

Comment: @user1071914 Understood.  I learned the importance of build/source control structure the hard way.  Unpleasant but educational ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of such a multi module project should look like this:

```
  pom.xml (parent)
   +--- module-1 (pom.xml)
   +--- module-2 (pom.xml)
```

The parent will be root of the git repository. This simplyfies your life either in working with such project (Eclipse or whatever IDE) and furthermore for Jenkins.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.   This will require some refactoring but I think it'll be worth it.

Comment: It's definitely worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the jenkins git plugin provides the same options but via svn it's possible to keep the Maven-Modules seperated from the parent.

Meening this structure:

```
parent
module-1
module-2
```

and a pom.xml like that:

```
<modules>
   <module>../module-1</module>
   <module>../module-2</module>
</modules>
```

The problem is that jenkins uses the following path for it's jobs:

```
<jenkins_home>/jobs/<parent-jobname>/workspace/
```

So that maven will look for the module poms in:

```
<jenkins_home>/jobs/<parent-jobname><module-name>
```

In the jobs svn-configuration you can define further modules to check out with a completely independent repo-path. Additionally you must define a local subfolder for the parent and one for each module maching the folder you used in the modules-section of the parent pom. So you will get the following Structure:

```
<jenkins_home>/jobs/<parent-jobname>/workspace/<parent-name>/pom.xml
<jenkins_home>/jobs/<parent-jobname>/workspace/module-1/pom.xml
<jenkins_home>/jobs/<parent-jobname>/workspace/module-2/pom.xml
```

And thats what Maven expects.